# How do I make a sound like this?

Tags: sound-design, creativity, noob

I really want to be able to make a lead that sounds like the one in the song below. 
I've asked the creator (Cargo), how he did it. Here's what he said:

- Used WW PanFlute from Nexus2
- Turned legato on
- Added a simple sound with a pulse wave
- Detuned it
- Add reverb and sidechain

I can't seem to get a good sound out of that, so do any of you have any suggestions?

Comment: You would need to also post _your_ attempt, so we can advise you more accurately.